# Missing EPSG:3035 in GDAL/QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, epsg

My fresh QGIS 3.10.3 installation from  `https://qgis.org/debian-ltr eoan main` via `apt install` on Ubuntu 19.10 is missing (at least) one CRS. More specifically, I cannot find/select the EPSG: 3035 within QGIS. At the same time the console output shows an error message: `ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.`

Any suggestions what got messed up here or if that's a bug within QGIS/GDAL?

**QGIS and OS versions**

```
QGIS version | 3.10.3-A Coruña | QGIS code revision | 0e1f846438
-- | -- | -- | --
Compiled against Qt | 5.12.4 | Running against Qt | 5.12.4
Compiled against GDAL/OGR | 2.4.2 | Running against GDAL/OGR | 2.4.2
Compiled against GEOS | 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 | Running against GEOS | 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1
Compiled against SQLite | 3.29.0 | Running against SQLite | 3.29.0
PostgreSQL Client Version | 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) | SpatiaLite Version | 4.3.0a
QWT Version | 6.1.4 | QScintilla2 Version | 2.10.4
Compiled against PROJ | 5.2.0 | Running against PROJ | Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
OS Version | Ubuntu 19.10
Active python plugins | openlayers_plugin; processing; db_manager; MetaSearch
```

***UPDATE:**

1) the environement variable `GDAL_DATA` is set to `/usr/share/gdal`; however this directory does not contain any gcs.csv file (it seems that gcs.csv files are not included any more in gdal: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1471)

2) The EPSG 3035 is also not found when using gdal directly:

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28

gdalsrsinfo EPSG:3035
ERROR 1: ERROR - failed to load SRS definition from EPSG:3035
```

Comment: I don't have neither on my Windows version 3.10.2

Comment: Works for me using Windows 10 with QGIS 3.10.3.

Comment: Did you try to set your GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files?

Comment: the GDAL_DATA environmental variable is set...I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: You have GDAL 2.4.2 so you should have the csv files. Change happened in version 2.5.